How do I add an Image Texture Node to a picture of a French Bulldog?
When I click Add > Texture > Image Texture, the options are all greyed out (I cant click them).
Here screenshots for further help


What are you trying to add a texture to? You have no material, you have to select an object that supports materials (not an empty), add a material, and add a texture to the material.
